# What does the elements.getBoundingBox output mean? (FirebaseVision, android)

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

When using the getBoundingBox method on an element extracted with the Firebase-MLKit library it gives you an output that looks like this

`Rect(0, 0 - 13, 33)`

what does each individual number represent?

relevant code

```
private void processTextRecognitionResults(FirebaseVisionText receipt) {

        List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = receipt.getTextBlocks();
        List<FirebaseVisionText.Element> elements;
        if (blocks.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No text found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        for (int runThroBlocks = 0; runThroBlocks < blocks.size(); runThroBlocks++) {
            List<FirebaseVisionText.Line> lines = blocks.get(runThroBlocks).getLines();
            for (int runThroLines = 0; runThroLines < lines.size(); runThroLines++) {
                elements = lines.get(runThroLines).getElements();
                for (int runThroElemnts = 0; runThroElemnts < elements.size(); runThroElemnts++) {
                    System.out.println("-----BOX-----");
                    System.out.println(elements.get(runThroElemnts).getText());
                    //This line prints the output given above
                    System.out.println(elements.get(runThroElemnts).getBoundingBox());
                    System.out.println("-----BOX-----");

                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry if the question is not written well. Its my first time writing one
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getBoundingBox()` function returns a [`android.graphics.Rect` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html).

The [`toString` implementation](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Rect.java#L151) that is invoked when you print `elements.get(runThroElemnts).getText()` prints them as `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom`.

> ```
>     public String toString() {
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
>         sb.append("Rect("); sb.append(left); sb.append(", ");
>         sb.append(top); sb.append(" - "); sb.append(right);
>         sb.append(", "); sb.append(bottom); sb.append(")");
>         return sb.toString();
>     }
> ```

Comment: First of all thank you for the help.
Are the "left, top, right, bottom" represented in pixels from the middle? or as dp's from the boundaries?